# stackApply with multivariate function in R

Tags: r

I am looking to use `stackApply()` in the raster package and approx() to linearly interpolate a grid cell of one raster between a stack of rasters. I have written a similar function that does this calculation on a dataframe, but would like to preform this on the stack of rasters rather than rows in a dataframe. I have found previous examples of using stackApply() with a user defined function, but none that involve multiple variables.

In other words, I have a stack of rasters and a lone raster grid (they have matching extent and resolution). I want to "drill" through the stack, cell by cell, to create a vector of values and linearly interpolate the value of the matching grid cell in the lone raster with the stack-created vector.

My code is along the lines of...

```
require(raster)
set.seed(42) 
x1 <- runif(100) 
x2 <- x1 
x3 <- x1 
x1[sample(1:100, 30)] <- NA 
x2[sample(1:100, 30)] <- NA 
x3[sample(1:100, 30)] <- NA 
r1 <- raster(matrix(x1, nrow=10, ncol=10)) 
r2 <- raster(matrix(x2, nrow=10, ncol=10)) 
r3 <- raster(matrix(x3, nrow=10, ncol=10)) 
s <- stack(r1, r2)

myfunc <- function(x,y){approx(x,c(0,1),y)}
newrast <- stackApply(stack,c(1,2), fun=myfunc(s,r3))
```

I am confused on how to pass multiple variables into the fun= argument in stackApply. I am also unsure on the ind= argument. I want to make sure that the function is being done through all layers, rather than on an entire layer individually and then repeated for each layer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that `stackApply` does not apply here. You would use `calc` instead.

For approx-like problems, you can consider `raster::approxNA`

```
s <- stack(r1, r2, r3)
x <- approxNA(s)
```

But if that does not work, you can do things like

```
f <- function(x) x[1] * sum(x[-1])
y <- calc(s, f)
```

alternatively, consider `overlay`

```
s <- stack(r1, r2)
z <- overlay(s, r3, fun=function(x, y) x * y)
```

(I would implement the function you are after, but I have no idea what you mean with "interpolate the value of the matching grid cell in the lone raster with the stack-created vector")

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand your confusion since it's a concept I am still trying to wrap my head around too. I will look into calc or overlay rather than stackApply, though I do not think approxNA is quite what I am looking for.  For my actual solution, I have a raster stack of 10 grids and 1 separate raster. For each cell value in the single raster, I want to grab all 10 values from the stack and linearly interpolate where the single cell value falls within the 10 using approx().

Comment: Is it possible to use `calc()` in the raster package and use `approx()` as the supplied funciton?

Comment: yes, you can do something like `f <- function(x, y) approx(1:10, y, x)$y` (where 10 would be the number of layers). But to make things clear you should really show the function you say you have (for a vector and a value)